# Where are the angular js scripts on Azure?

Tags: angularjs, azure, model-view-controller, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service

A client has asked us to look at a web app hosted by Azure.  I have some of the source code and access to the Azure site.  Part of the source code I have (locally, not on Azure) is several controllers (which I think are written in angular js).  These are files like browseController.js, index.js, etc.  These js files are on my local computer.  I'm trying to figure out where to put them on Azure after I've made changes to them in Visual Studio, but I can't find the js files anywhere in Azure.  I did find some js files in Azure with names like bundle-app.js and bundle-external.js, but when I open those files they don't look like any of the controller js files I have.

So, where would these js files be in Azure?

Here's the complete tree in Azure:

[image]

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether or not you have access to the source Visual Studio **solution** (source code) of the project.  The screenshots appear to be of the contents of the site as-is on Azure.  I'd suggest that the source application is bundling, and **minifying** all your controllers into `bundle-app.js`, and the process of minification is why they don't look familiar.  You really need to get the source code, run the process (I would guess grunt task that performs the bundling / minification) to generate the `bundle-app.js` and then upload that to Azure.

Comment: I do have access to some of the source code.  I have the js controllers and I can make changes to them (but not run or debug the project) in Visual Studio (locally), but then how do I get my changes to Azure?  Can you explain how this bundling and minifying work?  I've not done with with the C#/asp.net project I usually work with.  What do I do in Visual Studio to do this bundling and minifying?

Comment: Do you know how the app was deployed to Azure? I have a personal web application deployed to Azure using continuous deployment with a git repo. If thats the case, a solution to your problem might be as simple as cloning the git repo from azure and commiting updates to source code that way.

Comment: What version of ASP.Net is this project?  Is this ASP.Net 4.5 / MVC5, or is it the newer ASP.NET Core / MVC6?

Comment: I do not know how the app was deployed to Azure.  The client gave us a zip file of "all" the source code.  It contained a VS project and a lot of js controllers.  It won't run locally because it's missing several files (js and HTML that I've since found on Azure, but don't know how to download) and doesn't appear to have any connection to a data source (the data seems to be in blobs on Azure).  I'd appreciate any insight you can give me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use .NET MVC you will have a class called BundleConfig under AppStart in the web project. There you can configure how to bundle your javascript files. It is common that the bundles will be minified before deploying the application to Azure to decrease loading times which is why you doesn't recognize any of your controllers in there.

Read more here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification